# How to I change the content by id of tag in CKEditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, replace, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to change to the content with id in CKEditor. I will create a table in CKEditor like a template. I researched in help doc (http://docs.ckeditor.com/) but I couldn't find how to do.

I want to add the content I write in the text box when I clicked the button.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/mstfcck/m2g4mj83/

```
CKEDITOR.replace('RichTextEditor');
CKEDITOR.instances.RichTextEditor.setData("<div id='message'>This is a message.</div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the getById() and setText() like in the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('RichTextEditor');
CKEDITOR.instances.RichTextEditor.setData("<div id='message'>This is a message.</div>");
$("#change").on("click", function(){
    var element = CKEDITOR.instances.RichTextEditor.document.getById( 'message' );
    element.setText($("#messageBox").val());
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2g4mj83/5/

Here is the documentation for both:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-getById

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setText